# how can I find the convergence of the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+n^2x^2)}{n^2}~dx$ , for $ x \in [0,1]$

Tags: integration, functions, convergence-divergence

I want to check the convergence of the integral 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+n^2x^2)}{n^2} dx $$  for $ x \in [0,1]$ 
and  n->∞ is a constant so can basically pulled out of the integral but I don't know what to do. Every theory I know it is not working. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: We miss the integration variable...

Comment: the x is the integration variable.

Comment: So better you add a $dx$ to both the integrals (in the title and in the text).

Comment: Did you try integration by parts ?

Comment: You have a smooth and bounded function in a close interval, without any singular point in the interval. So I can't see what is your problem demonstrating the integral converges.

Comment: What is $n$? Is it an integer? In any case, $\frac{1}{n^2}$ can be removed from the integral - it doesn't affect the convergence in any way

Comment: I suspect that you want to ask about the convergence of the integral when $n \to \infty$, not about whether the integral is finite or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each non complex constant $n\neq0$ and for $x$ in $[0, 1]$, we have $|\ln(1+n^2x^2)|<\ln(1+n^2)$ so: $$\int_{0}^{1}\left | \frac{\ln(1+n^2x^2)}{n^2} \right | dx < \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+n^2)}{n^2} dx = \frac{\ln(1+n^2)}{n^2}.$$ So the integral is absolutelly convergent.

The limit for $n \rightarrow 0$ deserves a separate tractation...

Comment: I believe that a typo was $n$ a non complex constant and $\neq 0$.

Comment: @user243301 uhmmm... yes... it was a typo.

Comment: thank you...that was it. and true n->∞, not in 0

Comment: @NickRaven, if you are asking about the limit $n \to \infty$ then **edit your question** and I will vote to reopen it